# pyaudio give me an error everytime I try to install

Tags: python, pip, pyaudio

When installing pyaudio with python I get this error, Does anyone know what this is or has had this problem before?

```
C:\Users\BeanieGod>python -m pip install pyaudio
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc196ce156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command 'C:\Users\BeanieGod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\BEANIE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-bjzqgxub\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\BEANIE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-t5y6dz6q\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 -IC:\Users\BeanieGod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include -IC:\Users\BeanieGod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
    _portaudiomodule.c
    src/_portaudiomodule.c(27): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'C:\Users\BeanieGod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\BEANIE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-bjzqgxub\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\BEANIE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-t5y6dz6q\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\BEANIE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bjzqgxub\pyaudio\
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpyaudio%5D+%5Bpip%5D+install

Answer (score 0):

Try download the .whl from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio (be carefull to choose the right version -- `PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl`?) and run:

`pip install PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl`